# While loop stuck in range condition

Tags: python, while-loop, range

I'm trying to ask a user for a integer input. If the input is within the range it iterates through a list to find its matching value. If the input is not within the range, it asks the user to enter an input within a specified range. However, for some reason the value will continue to be counted as false and the loop will continue infinitely.

```
choice1 = input("Select an option from the menu: ")
if choice1 == '1':
    year = int(input("Please enter a year: "))
    while not year>=1920 or year<=2020:
        year = int(input("Please enter a year within range: "))
```

So regardless of whether or not the number is in range, it will immediately go to the 'while not' condition and stay there. I tried using "in range," however, I still run into same issue

Comment: The `not` only applies to the first condition. So it is "while the year is not larger than 1919, or while the year is smaller than 2021". So any year below 2021 will cause the loop to continue.

Comment: Use parentheses, like `while not (year >= 1920 and year <= 2020)` (I think you intend "and", not "or"), but probably clearer, invert the condition: `while year < 1920 or year > 2020`.

Answer (score -1):

The precedence rules mean:

```
while not year>=1920 or year<=2020:
```

is parsed as:

```
while (not (year>=1920)) or (year<=2020):
```

So any number that is not greater than/equal to 1920, *or* is less than/equal to 2020 is accepted (which effectively means you'll accept any number less than/equal to 2020; any number that is less than 1920, failing the first test, will be less than 2020, passing the second).

If you want to range test like this, I suggest:

```
while not (1920 <= year <= 2020):
# Parentheses not *needed*, so you could do:
while not 1920 <= year <= 2020:
# but the relative precedence of not and the chained comparison isn't always obvious
# so the parens make it more maintainer friendly
```

which not only reads a little more clearly ("while the year is not between 1920 and 2020"), it's also *slightly* more performant (it only loads `year` once). The minimalist fixes could just be:

```
while not year>=1920 or not year<=2020:
# or undistributing the not
while not (year>=1920 and year<=2020):
# or checking for failures rather than checking for successes then inverting:
while year < 1920 or year > 2020:
```

but as long as you're using Python which allows conditional chaining, I consider `while not (1920 <= year <= 2020):` the cleanest option (`while year < 1920 or year > 2020:` is also fine, but the other two are uglier and very easy to get wrong).

Comment: Just remote the whole "not": it is clearer without, in my opinion.

Comment: @9769953: Yeah, I added that as an option. I *slightly* prefer `while not (1920 <= year <= 2020):` for reading like English while avoiding multiple negations; you define the "good" criteria succinctly with the chained check for being within the valid range, then invert the meaning from good to bad as a single step. But explicitly describing the failure cases that require looping with `while year < 1920 or year > 2020:` is not terrible (it's just really easy for newbies to get the choice of `or` vs. `and` wrong).